# GWT : style injector (slow in IE)

Tags: gwt, internet-explorer-8

Our GWT application is taking more than one minute for its initial rendering in IE8 (the network is not an issue as everything is on the local machine). When profiling using dev. tools (F12), it seems the issue is related to StyleInjectorImplIE.injectStyleSheetAtEnd() that takes all the time.

Any idea or suggestion about what can go wrong ?

PS : Does not have this issue with IE9; neither for FF, Chrome, Safari, ...

Comment: No - the application has been built for production.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using gwt-log ?  We had the same issue and traced it to this package, it started using  CSS injection as of 3.0.0